# Way to enumerate all elliptic curve names available in Java?

Tags: java, cryptography, elliptic-curve

Is there some way to enumerate all of the elliptic curve names that can be given to
the [`ECGenParameterSpec`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/spec/ECGenParameterSpec.html) constructor?  Or do you have to just throw a big list of curve names at the wall and see which ones do or don't throw execeptions when you try to use them?

Comment: `java.security.Security.getAlgorithms()` - no idea how to tell which are elliptic curves though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends very much on the provider you want to use. As stated by [user69513](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9175160/user69513), you'll want to consult the documentation. And there lies the most basic of problems.

For the SunEC provider, the documentation is nowhere to be found, nor are the sources available to the public. But by going through the exposed classes in sunec.jar we find the **CurveDB** class and a method **getSupportedCurves**. One could call that using reflection:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Method method = sun.security.ec.CurveDB.class.getDeclaredMethod("getSupportedCurves", null);
    method.setAccessible(true);
    Collection result = (Collection) method.invoke(null, null);
    for (Object object : result) {
        System.out.println(object);
    }
}
```

This provides you with full discolure:

```
secp112r1 (1.3.132.0.6)
secp112r2 (1.3.132.0.7)
secp128r1 (1.3.132.0.28)
secp128r2 (1.3.132.0.29)
secp160k1 (1.3.132.0.9)
secp160r1 (1.3.132.0.8)
secp160r2 (1.3.132.0.30)
secp192k1 (1.3.132.0.31)
secp192r1 [NIST P-192, X9.62 prime192v1] (1.2.840.10045.3.1.1)
secp224k1 (1.3.132.0.32)
secp224r1 [NIST P-224] (1.3.132.0.33)
secp256k1 (1.3.132.0.10)
secp256r1 [NIST P-256, X9.62 prime256v1] (1.2.840.10045.3.1.7)
secp384r1 [NIST P-384] (1.3.132.0.34)
secp521r1 [NIST P-521] (1.3.132.0.35)
X9.62 prime192v2 (1.2.840.10045.3.1.2)
X9.62 prime192v3 (1.2.840.10045.3.1.3)
X9.62 prime239v1 (1.2.840.10045.3.1.4)
X9.62 prime239v2 (1.2.840.10045.3.1.5)
X9.62 prime239v3 (1.2.840.10045.3.1.6)
sect113r1 (1.3.132.0.4)
sect113r2 (1.3.132.0.5)
sect131r1 (1.3.132.0.22)
sect131r2 (1.3.132.0.23)
sect163k1 [NIST K-163] (1.3.132.0.1)
sect163r1 (1.3.132.0.2)
sect163r2 [NIST B-163] (1.3.132.0.15)
sect193r1 (1.3.132.0.24)
sect193r2 (1.3.132.0.25)
sect233k1 [NIST K-233] (1.3.132.0.26)
sect233r1 [NIST B-233] (1.3.132.0.27)
sect239k1 (1.3.132.0.3)
sect283k1 [NIST K-283] (1.3.132.0.16)
sect283r1 [NIST B-283] (1.3.132.0.17)
sect409k1 [NIST K-409] (1.3.132.0.36)
sect409r1 [NIST B-409] (1.3.132.0.37)
sect571k1 [NIST K-571] (1.3.132.0.38)
sect571r1 [NIST B-571] (1.3.132.0.39)
X9.62 c2tnb191v1 (1.2.840.10045.3.0.5)
X9.62 c2tnb191v2 (1.2.840.10045.3.0.6)
X9.62 c2tnb191v3 (1.2.840.10045.3.0.7)
X9.62 c2tnb239v1 (1.2.840.10045.3.0.11)
X9.62 c2tnb239v2 (1.2.840.10045.3.0.12)
X9.62 c2tnb239v3 (1.2.840.10045.3.0.13)
X9.62 c2tnb359v1 (1.2.840.10045.3.0.18)
X9.62 c2tnb431r1 (1.2.840.10045.3.0.20)
```

Comment: You can find the source code [here](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/6c7029ffd48186353fc1d2a03915386b5f386ae2/src/java.base/share/classes/sun/security/ec/SunEC.java#L215). The history of the file is interesting, all curves used to be returned but apparently some of them depended on native code and an if was then added in case native lib support was disabled. At some point, native curve were removed as well as the if that returned all curves, and that's why only 3 curves are turned by SupportedCurves attribute... something like that.

Comment: And the documentation can be found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/security/oracle-providers.html#GUID-091BF58C-82AB-4C9C-850F-1660824D5254__GUID-9B067ED7-7C4A-41E2-91F4-08C740A2E944). In the Java 8 version, only 3 curves were recommended and all the other curves were noted as "legacy". In the link I provided, there are 7 curves but the code (i.e. SupportedCurve attribute) has not been updated. [This](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8235184) may also be of interest (as well as related tickets).

Answer (score 9):

There is a better way to get hold of the list of supported curve names using supported APIs rather than reflection:

```
Security.getProviders("AlgorithmParameters.EC")[0]
    .getService("AlgorithmParameters", "EC").getAttribute("SupportedCurves");
```

In jshell (AdoptOpenJDK 11.0.1):

```
jshell> Security.getProviders("AlgorithmParameters.EC")[0]
    .getService("AlgorithmParameters", "EC").getAttribute("SupportedCurves")
$10 ==> "[secp112r1,1.3.132.0.6]|[secp112r2,1.3.132.0.7]|[secp128r1,1.3.132.0.28]|[secp128r2,1.3.132.0.29]|[secp160k1,1.3.132.0.9]|[secp160r1,1.3.132.0.8]|[secp160r2,1.3.132.0.30]|[secp192k1,1.3.132.0.31]|[secp192r1,NIST P-192,X9.62 prime192v1,1.2.840.10045.3.1.1]|[secp224k1,1.3.132.0.32]|[secp224r1,NIST P-224,1.3.132.0.33]|[secp256k1,1.3.132.0.10]|[secp256r1,NIST P-256,X9.62 prime256v1,1.2.840.10045.3.1.7]|[secp384r1,NIST P-384,1.3.132.0.34]|[secp521r1,NIST P-521,1.3.132.0.35]|[X9.62 prime192v2,1.2.840.10045.3.1.2]|[X9.62 prime192v3,1.2.840.10045.3.1.3]|[X9.62 prime239v1,1.2.840.10045.3.1.4]|[X9.62 prime239v2,1.2.840.10045.3.1.5]|[X9.62 prime239v3,1.2.840.10045 ... 840.10045.3.0.18]|[X9.62 c2tnb431r1,1.2.840.10045.3.0.20]|[brainpoolP160r1,1.3.36.3.3.2.8.1.1.1]|[brainpoolP192r1,1.3.36.3.3.2.8.1.1.3]|[brainpoolP224r1,1.3.36.3.3.2.8.1.1.5]|[brainpoolP256r1,1.3.36.3.3.2.8.1.1.7]|[brainpoolP320r1,1.3.36.3.3.2.8.1.1.9]|[brainpoolP384r1,1.3.36.3.3.2.8.1.1.11]|[brainpoolP512r1,1.3.36.3.3.2.8.1.1.13]"
```

You can then parse these entries.

However, there is now also the [new "XEC" curves](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/324) - X25519 and X448. As far as I am aware, these are only available as the [two constants of NamedParameterSpec](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/security/spec/NamedParameterSpec.html#field.detail).

Comment: This is much better than reflection, but unfortunately, you have to end up parsing a string description to find the individual curves. Tested and working on Java 8 and Java 11.

Comment: I don't know if it's better than reflection, this attribute only returns what the Provider wants it to return and not what it actually supports (e.g. for SunEC, only 3 curves are hardcoded but it supports much more).

Comment: Also, the provider (e.g. BouncyCastle) may not have defined this SupportedCurve attribute so it could just return null.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs for the [`ECGenParameterSpec`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/security/spec/ECGenParameterSpec.html) constructor:

> ... For the list of supported names, please consult the documentation of provider whose implementation will be used.

So the answer to (part of) your question is, you already have to know that the name you are passing is supported by whatever implementation you will be using.

---

As for enumerating various algorithms, I believe what you are after is [java.security.Security.getProviders(String filter)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/security/Security.html#getProviders-java.lang.String-).

`public static Provider[] getProviders(String filter)` ...

> Returns an array containing all installed providers that satisfy the specified selection criterion, or null if no such providers have been installed. ...

Also see [Java Security Standard Algorithm Names Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/specs/security/standard-names.html).

---

As for [`ECGenParameterSpec`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/security/spec/ECGenParameterSpec.html), its only internal member is the single `String` object that you pass to it. So what's up with that? Well, it implements [`AlgorithmParameterSpec`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/security/spec/AlgorithmParameterSpec.html), which (from the docs):

> ... This interface contains no methods or constants. Its only purpose is to group (and provide type safety for) all parameter specifications. All parameter specifications must implement this interface.