# secp256k1 is not working/supporting in eclipse?

Tags: java, cryptography, private-key, public-key, secp256k1

Getting this error:

> java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: Unsupported curve: secp256k1 (1.3.132.0.10)

is there any kind of method that i can use secp256k1 in eclipse? i cannot found any help. how i can use secp256k1 to generate a public and private key pair of the elliptic curve?

```
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.spec.ECGenParameterSpec;
import java.security.spec.*;

public class ECCKeyGeneration {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            KeyPairGenerator kpg;
            kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("EC");
            ECGenParameterSpec ecsp;
            ecsp = new ECGenParameterSpec("secp256k1");
            kpg.initialize(ecsp);

            KeyPair kp = kpg.genKeyPair();
            PrivateKey privKey = kp.getPrivate();
            PublicKey pubKey = kp.getPublic();

            System.out.println(privKey.toString());
            System.out.println(pubKey.toString());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: could you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48802735/way-to-enumerate-all-elliptic-curve-names-available-in-java

Answer (score 3):

Usually, this question depends on the Java version and not Eclipse. Kindly run the following program (slightly edited version of yours) and give us the version that is running on your machine.

This is an output of an online compiler (direct link: https://repl.it/@javacrypto/JavaEllipticCurveAvailable)

```
Java Version: main: 11 major: 0 minor: 8+10-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu118 update: 04 build: 1
sun.security.ec.ECPrivateKeyImpl@5403
Sun EC public key, 256 bits
  public x coord: 40409384899581786570368833959823834602401842042090899775653557207593518019107
  public y coord: 55894232296453671204408524113424724230763480655586911101265852946730642819727
  parameters: secp256k1 (1.3.132.0.10)
```

code:

```
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.spec.ECGenParameterSpec;
import java.security.spec.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.out.println("Java Version: " + getJavaVersion());
        try {
            KeyPairGenerator kpg;
            kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("EC");
            ECGenParameterSpec ecsp;
            ecsp = new ECGenParameterSpec("secp256k1");
            kpg.initialize(ecsp);

            KeyPair kp = kpg.genKeyPair();
            PrivateKey privKey = kp.getPrivate();
            PublicKey pubKey = kp.getPublic();

            System.out.println(privKey.toString());
            System.out.println(pubKey.toString());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }
    public static String getJavaVersion() {
        String[] javaVersionElements = System.getProperty("java.runtime.version").split("\\.|_|-b");
        String main = "", major = "", minor = "", update = "", build = "";
        int elementsSize = javaVersionElements.length;
        if (elementsSize > 0) {main = javaVersionElements[0];}
        if (elementsSize > 1) {major   = javaVersionElements[1];}
        if (elementsSize > 2) {minor   = javaVersionElements[2];}
        if (elementsSize > 3) {update  = javaVersionElements[3];}
        if (elementsSize > 4) {build   = javaVersionElements[4];}
        return "main: " + main + " major: " + major + " minor: " + minor + " update: " + update + " build: " + build;
    }
}
```

Comment: my java version is 15JDK

Comment: Java Version: main: 15+36 major:  minor:  update:  build: 
java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: Unsupported curve: secp256k1 (1.3.132.0.10)

Comment: can i change my jdk 15 to 11?

Comment: thanks a lot now it is working i change my java version

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution for your actual problem via "downgrading". Please keep in mind that the curve "secp256k1" got removed by Oracle (respective announcement in 2019) so you may change the curve to be safe in future.Could you kindly mark my answer as accepted one, thanks ?

Comment: In particular see the release notes at https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/15-relnote-issues.html#JDK-8237219 .

Answer (score 3):

// specific reliable provider, that works even java 17+

`KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("EC", "BC")`

Comment: This assumes you did `Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider())
` somewhere in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Eclipse and OpenJDK.

The minimum requirement - OpenJDK version 11.0.5

```java
public static void main(String[] args) 
    throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException {

    KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("EC");

    ECGenParameterSpec m = new ECGenParameterSpec("secp256k1");

    kpg.initialize(m);

    ECPrivateKey privateKey = (ECPrivateKey) kpg.generateKeyPair().getPrivate();

    ECPublicKey publicKey = (ECPublicKey) kpg.generateKeyPair().getPublic();

    System.out.println("Base64 encoded private key : " + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(privateKey.getEncoded()));

    System.out.println("Base64 encoded public key : " + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(publicKey.getEncoded()));
}
```